# Can't run any commands in terminal

Tags: magento2.3, fatal-error, error-log

I'm facing the terrible issue, I can't run any commands via terminal. It says the below error:

> Class Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Proxy does not exist

In frontend:

[image]

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: did you create any new module ?

Comment: I have installed a module but that wasn't worked so I have disabled the module. After then I can't run any commands. It says the above mentioned error

Comment: please copy and remove  new added module and try

Comment: I have done that as well

Comment: then now you can run commands ?

Comment: try removing generated folder and clear cache

Comment: yes, remove generated folder also

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2.3.3 Commerce. It was related with optimize parameter for me.

```
composer dump-autoload --optimize
```

I noticed it needed to run the command with optimize twice

```
php7.2 /usr/local/bin/composer dump-autoload --no-dev -o
Generating optimized autoload files
php7.2 bin/magento setup:di:compile
Class Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Proxy does not exist

php7.2 /usr/local/bin/composer dump-autoload --no-dev -o
Generating optimized autoload files
php7.2 bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
Interception cache generation... 7/7 [============================] 100% 49 secs 446.0 MiB
Generated code and dependency injection configuration successfully.
```

Also, second running worked longer than first running.
It's strange and I don't understand the reason such behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was new added  module and its naming conventions.

First you need to disable/ remove your new added module. Then delete your generated and cache code folder and `run php bin/magento setup:upgrade and php bin/magento setup:di:compile commands.`

Hope it will fix your issue.